# How does strlen giving the same output for {'1','1'} and {'1','1','\0'}?

Tags: c, arrays, null, strlen

strlen() is terminated by null right? So how come both char c[]={'1','1'} and char d[]={'1','1','\0'} gives the same output 2 when strlen(c) and strlen(d) is used?

Comment: `\0` is the symbol for string termination not null

Comment: Probably there just happens to be a 0 in memory after the 2nd element in the `c` array.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu The **C99 standard** calls strings “null-terminated” (p303, for instance). The OP is referring to the null character, whereas you may be thinking of null pointers or `NULL` (which is not guaranteed to be a pointer).

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq Yes but that does not mean you can put `NULL` instead of `\0`. `\0` is the null terminator. And from this question I deduced that he does not know the difference or rather the similarity between `NULL` and `\0`.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu Your suggestion “… is the symbol for string termination not null” is more confusing than the minor mistake of using “terminated by null” for “null-terminated” in the question. You are correcting a mistake that the OP did not make and you are using the word “null” in a strange way that does not correspond to how it is used in the C standard.

Comment: I just wanted to point something that is very easy to see when you watch a string variable in the debugger, that at the end it has `\0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former is undefined behavior; it could output 2, it could also output 500, terminate your program or destroy your computer.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen(d)` will return 2, no problem with that.

`strlen(c)` will return >= 2.
If the char at position c+2 == '\0', then you are lucky and `strlen(c)` returns 2, but you can't have any guarantee of that!

Answer (score 1):

> strlen() is terminated by null right?

I think some confusion arises from using the wrong terminology: "strlen" is the name of a C standard function; functions are not "terminated by null". If you mean that strlen is supposed to work on sequences of characters that are null-terminated, where "null-terminated" means that a '\0' is the final sentinel character determining the end of the sequence, then yes: strlen does that.

Note that NULL (all in capitals) is normally defined as an alias for 0 (in stddef.h).

All above said, however, the two arrays of characters 'c' and 'd' in your example have different contents. The former contains two items, the latter three. A valid input for strlen would just be your 'd' array. Your array 'c' is not null-terminated.

The reason strlen is returning the correct length anyway is that the area where 'c' is allocated contains, by pure chance, a '\0' after the last item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that you got luck.

The strlen() function will start to count until it founds a '\0'.

In your d string, you put the '\0' at the end of your string. The strlen func returns 2 caracters then.

In your second one, by luck, in your memory you got many '\0' everywhere and the character at the end of your c string is a '\0'. So, it returns the same value ;)

Comment: If something works because of undefined behaviour, I would call it a *bad* luck.

Answer (score 0):

\0 marks the terminating character of the string not NULL. strlen doesn't count the terminating character when given a string, it will count until it finds \0 and then stop and return.

Also when writing

char a[]="hello" ;

this allocates 6 memory spaces 5 for the hello and 1 for the \0.
In most cases strlen(c) will not be 2

Comment: Nobody is talking about `NULL` except you.